# Java: I do not Understand the Relative Paths

Tags: java, relative-path

I've got following maven project structure as also seen in here ([ProjectStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNxl8.png)) :

```
-maws20.algorithm
 |-src/main/resources
   |-images
     |-menuBanner
       |-linearSearchMenuBannerUnsorted.png
 |-src/main/java
   |-linearSearch.menu
     |-LinearSearchMenuBanner.java
```

I am trying to load that .png image inside of the LinearSearchMenuBanner.java-File with the following Line:

```
@Override
public Image loadBackgroundImage() {
   return new Image(LinearSearchMenuBanner.class.
       getResource("/images/menuBanner/linearSearchMenuBannerUnsorted.png").toString());
}
```

Is this not the correct relative path? Because I get the following error:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toString()" because the return value of "java.lang.Class.getResource(String)" is null
    at linearSearch.menu.LinearSearchMenuBanner.loadBackgroundImage(LinearSearchMenuBanner.java:20)
...
```

(Line 20 is the line shown above)

I thought I understood the relative paths in Java. ^^'

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try removing the first / from "/images/..."

Comment: A path with "/" is absolute, not relative.

Comment: With relative path you start from the "place" (position) where you are currently and ignore content above. That is, related to your position, but you can go above  with "../".

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first back slash `/`, which actually means absolute path not the relative path.
Try this:

```
@Override
public Image loadBackgroundImage() {
    File resource = new ClassPathResource("images/menuBanner/linearSearchMenuBannerUnsorted.png").getFile();
    return new Image(new String(Files.readAllBytes(resource.toPath()));
}
```

To know more, you can visit this link: [spring-classpath-file-access](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get still the same error. :(

Comment: Updated the answer. let me know if this works? @Schrello

Comment: Hey, if I use the Spring.Framework, then i get 

'java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [images/menuBanner/linearSearchMenuBannerUnsorted.png] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist'

(How can I format sth. as code in the comment-section?)

Why does the URL not exists? It is there.

Comment: Yes..  I also tried to use the absolut path like: "F:\\Eigene Daten\\....\\images\\menuBanner\\linearSearchMenuBannerUnsorted.png" Stil getting the message, that the URL does not exists. 

I think something else seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is related to your packaging. The image needs to be on the servers file system, the JAR resources will not work!

[ClassPathResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html)

```
Supports resolution as java.io.File if the class path resource resides in the file system, but not for resources in a JAR. Always supports resolution as URL.
```

You are in package `search.menu` and you need to access the file resource in `images/menuBanner` So you need to load a resource:

```
new ClassPathResource(“../../images/menuBanner/linearSearchMenuBannerUnsorted.png
“, LinearSearchMenuBanner
.class).getFile();
```

Hava a look into other options here: 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But then it should still work with 

.class.getResource("images/menuBanner/linearSearchMenuBannerUnsorted.png").toString());

Shouldn't it?

Comment: @Schrello: I think this answer comes closest to the solution. The other answers seem to be confused about the difference between absolute paths on the file system and absolute paths on the class path. Your path look right to me.

Comment: @Schrello: `Class.getResource` looks for resources at the same place as where your class files are stored for the running application. Have you verified that the image file is available at that place? (That place should be a jar file or a bin directory, probably `<project name>/bin` in Eclipse.)

Comment: Thank you... Why doesn't it work with getRessource() ?  Why doesn't it work at all? :(

Comment: @Schrello Loading a resource is dependent on the ClassLoader. Understanding the mechanics of ClassLoaders is key to this. With a ClassLoader you have control what happens and can do plugin sandboxing and more. Normally there's a security aspect to it. You can try using an URL as this should always work and is easier to test if setup correctly. Also you can enforce the use of a dedicated ClassLoader (ONLY DO THIS IF YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING  - you can create security loopholes in your app in the worst case).

Comment: @Lii I don't understand what you mean... The images are in the same Directory as the project folders and the jar files. There ist something else broken, I think.. I cannot even open the image with the absolut path like "C:\\Eigene Daten\\...\\linearSearchMenuBannerUnsorted.png". At least this should work. But it doesn't. :/

Comment: @Schrello:
Using a different Classloader would look like this:
'return new ClassPathResource("path/to/my/file.txt", this.getClass().getClassLoader());' (this can be replaced by any class). I'd still suggest you go the standard way and put the files onto the server as the AppServer can then take care centrally about security and access or use URL access.

Comment: @supernova I used resource = new ClassPathResource("images/menuBanner/linearSearchMenuBannerUnsorted.png").getFile(); like ruhul suggested. But it didn't work.

How do I go the standard way and put the images onto the server?

Comment: @Schrello added some more information. You should be able to read the file with all those infos.

Comment: @Schrello: When your code is built the resulting .class files are copied to an output directory or jar files. Your image resources are often also copied to this output directory as a part of the build process, and read from that directory by `Class.getResource`. In Eclipse that directory is often called `<project name>/bin`. Check if the file is really copied to that place! (That directory is hidden in *Package Explorer* so you have to use Windows Explorer.)

Comment: @supernova Thank you. I used: _resource = new ClassPathResource("../../images/menuBanner/linearSearchMenuBannerUnsorted.png", LinearSearchMenuBanner.class).getFile();
   return new Image(new String(Files.readAllBytes(resource.toPath())));_

And still get the Error "cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. I don't know what went wrong, but when i create a completly new Workspace after that create all files new and copy the source code to the new files. Then it works fine.

I dont know why...

But thank you very much :)